# Migration error while switching to new Google Maps SDK

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I've followed the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration), so I did the following changes in build.gradle

Prerequisites:

1. It was working before switching
2. Required Maps API are enabled
3. Billing is also enabled
4. Correct API key is used

```
dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.1.0'
}
```

Now I get variable error for `PLACE_DETECTION_API` and `GeoDataApi`

This is how I implemented search in the activity

SeachActivity.java

```java
        //onCreate() method
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

     @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> result = 
        Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, "infopark", null, null);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onConnected: Result" + autocompletePredictions);
            }
        });
    }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> doInBackground(String... params) {

            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + strAddress);

                PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                        Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, strAddress, null,
                                        null);

                AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                        .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                final com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status = 
                autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
                if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + 
                    status.toString());
                    autocompletePredictions.release();
                    return null;
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                        + " predictions.");
                return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
            return null;
        }
```

SearchResultsRecycler.java

```java
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtPlace = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_place);
            txtAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_address);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AutocompletePrediction item = mResultList.get(getLayoutPosition());
                    String placeId = item.getPlaceId();
                    CharSequence primaryText = item.getPrimaryText(null);

                    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                    placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I changed the initialization to:

```java
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
```

Still the error exists. I've seen various answers here, some tell to use intent, fragment, still the same problem. It's quite confusing.

Comment: Please check out my answer below and let me know if the solutions work. If the issue persists, please share the errors you get in your logcat and provide your full code so that we can reproduce this from our side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are depending on the deprecated SDK, the client library and the compatibility library. You can only implement one of those 3. Try removing these 2 dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.1.0'
```

So that you only implement the client library in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
```

Then make sure that you have:

(1) migrated to AndroidX

(2) imported the client library via `import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places`

(3) enabled the [Places API](https://cloud.google.com/console/apis/library/places-backend.googleapis.com) on your project

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helped, now I'm currently using the fragment method.

Comment: Glad to hear! :)